# Cerrar una ventana desde python

Tags: python

He usado el código de la librería os para abrir una ventana de google.

```
import os

os.startfile("C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Google Chrome")
```

me gustaría agregar time.sleep y luego cerrar esa ventana, pero no tengo idea de como hacerlo.

Comment: Puede que esto te sirva https://stackoverflow.com/a/20218672/4326551

Answer (score 2):

[`os.startfile()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.startfile) es una rutina especifica para windows, básicamente invoca el programa asociado al archivo que le pasas por parámetro, vale decir que si haces `os.startfile(archivo.txt)` lo más probable es que te abra el `notepad` o algún programa que tengas registrado para dicha extensión. Además no te va a retornar ningún identificador de proceso que te sirva luego para matar la aplicación.

En tu ejemplo estás queriendo abrir un programa ejecutable por lo que la forma más óptima sería haciendo uso [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess), de la siguiente forma:

```
import subprocess
proc = subprocess.Popen("C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Google Chrome", shell=False)
```

`Popen` devuelve un objeto `<subprocess.Popen>` que te permitirá luego finalizar el proceso, usando el metódo [`terminate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess) de la siguiente forma:

```
proc.terminate()
```